# Is it safe to inject persistent entity in @RequestMapping using @AuthenticationPrincipal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd like to know if it is safe to inject the persistent entity via `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in a method annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

My concern is following:

```
@GetMapping("/orders")
public List<OrderDto> getOrders(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) { ... }
```

in the code above, the method should return all orders for currently logged user (which it does), however, if I modify the code as follows

```
@GetMapping("/orders")
public List<OrderDto> getOrders(User user) { ... }
```

then I'm able to retrieve orders for all users (by changing the user's role to admin in the http request). Is something like this possible while using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`? How does the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation ensure that the possible attacker would not be able to inject some malicious code to the entity?

To clarify, the `User` entity is annotated with `@Entity`.

I'm currently using Spring Security 5.1.4.

Comment: It's a *bad idea* to do this, because the principal needs to be able to be detached and stored with the session. Standard practice is to put the PK into a `UserDetails` or similar data object.

Comment: You can transfer User object without using annotations? I think that possible only with "simple" types, like primitives, String etc.: [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html)

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko Yes, you can if you send the object's properties in query params and have setters on the User class. Spring will 'figure it out' and constructs the User object with the properties from the request for you.